# pipewire libcamera spa missing or broken

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pipewire

I just setup a new Arch Linux install on a custom build. I chose to use pipewire with wireplumber. But wireplumber is having some issues, and I can't figure out how to install what it's complaining about. The error I see when running `systemctl --user status wireplumber.service` is

```
Started Multimedia Service Session Manager.
Failed to set scheduler settings: Operation not permitted
reserve-device plugin is not connected to D-Bus, disabling device reservation
SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.manager' could not be loaded; is it installed?
PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing or broken. libcamera not supported.
```

Where do i get this `libcamera SPA` and how/where do I install it? I haven't had much luck searching around online.

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora, I installed package `pipewire-plugin-libcamera`, and this warning disappeared and was replaced with:

```
Oct 25 17:47:24 edison wireplumber[57720]: [1:45:09.575925146] [57720]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0
```

See https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2020/09/11/integrating-libcamera-into-pipewire/ for more details about libcamera and its integration with Pipewire. The basic idea is that Pipewire can stream the camera device data into multiple applications simultaneously.